# in Swift, How do I display a string of hex values as decimal in the text field of a UILabel

Tags: swift, type-conversion

My code:

```
var analogData = String(recieveCharacteristic!.value)
analogSensor.text = "\(analogData)"
```

The output looks something like:

`"Optional(<31303230>)"`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have to unwrap the optional with a `!`.

To get rid of the `Optional(...)` you need to change:

```
"\(analogData)"
```

to

```
"\(analogData!)"
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a piece of data to string, use the `init?(data:encoding:)` constructor.

```
let analogData = String(data: recieveCharacteristic!.value, encoding: .utf8)!
```